# Matplotlib with "secondary_y": How do I reposition the legend to the bottom left?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, legend

Sorry, I'm a beginner. The legend shows up by itself when I run the code and I have no idea how to move it around. I tried the ax function from other answers but it says that it is not defined. Also, the label from `plt.ylabel` will only show on the side of the secondary_y, so how do I put a label on the other side of the y-axis?

```
IBISEQ_df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": IB_df['Date'], "AIBG.I": IB_df['AIB'], "BIRG": IB_df['BoI'], "ISEQ": ISEQ_df['Close']}) 
IBISEQ_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ISEQ_df['Date'])
IBISEQ_df.dropna(inplace = True, axis = 0)
IBISEQ_df.plot(x = 'Date', secondary_y = ["AIBG.I", "BIRG"], grid = True, figsize = (18,8))
plt.title('3-Year Stock Performance of AIB and BoI vs Irish Stock Exchange Index')
```

Does anyone have a solution? I'd appreciate every input. Thank you!

This is the output of the code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default value for the legend location by inserting this line somewhere before the plotting commands:

```py
plt.rcParams['legend.loc'] = 'lower left'
```

This should work, because `df.plot()` invokes `matplotlib.pyplot.legend()` to draw the legend. See the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html).